# A Limit of a function involving big O notation.

Tags: calculus

Fix $t$, I was wondering am I allowed to compute the following limit?

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n \left(\frac{-t^2}{2n} + O(\frac{1}{n}) \right)$$

I'm quite confused about such O-notation.. is this limit equal to $\frac{-t^2}{2} ?$

Comment: It will give you some help maybe. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113095/the-big-o-versus-little-o-notation?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the limit cannot be determined. $O\left(\dfrac1n\right)$ represents a function of $n$ whose absolute value is bounded by $\dfrac Cn$ for some constant $C$. Thus, $n\,O\left(\dfrac1n\right)$ is bounded independent of $n$, but does not necessarily tend to a limit.

However, if the expression used [little-o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation), *then*
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{-t^2}{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=-\dfrac{t^2}{2}
$$
since by definition of little-o,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\,o\left(\frac1n\right)=0
$$

Comment: Thanks @robjohn, I read the paragraph about little-o but still not quite understand why the $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \cdot o(1/n) =0$. Could you say more word about this line?

Comment: @Fianra: pretty much, that is the definition of little-o: $f(n)=o(g(n))$ means that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$$

Comment: Thank you so much. @robjohn, but I just want to make sure I got your main point: so in my question, $f(n) = o(1/n)$ and $g(n)=1/n$ So I get $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n \cdot o(\frac{1}{n}) = 0$? Am I saying this wary correct?

Comment: @Fianra: precisely. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{o(1/n)}{1/n}=0$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. As my understanding, we say $f(n)\in O(\frac{1}{n})$ means $\exists$ constant $C$, s.t. $|f(n)|\leq C|\frac{1}{n}|$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. But $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n O(\frac{1}{n})$ may not exist. For example, $\frac{1}{n}\sin(n)\in O(\frac{1}{n})$, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin(n)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much we are able to say about this limit.

Used in an expression like that, $O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ expresses some function $f(n)$ bounded above by $\frac{c}{n}$. Hence, $$n \left( \frac{-t^2}{2n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right) = n\left(\frac{-t^2}{2n} + f(n)\right) \leq n\left(\frac{-t^2}{2n} + \frac{c}{n}\right) = \frac{-t^2}{2} + c$$.

So, we can say at least that the limit is bounded above by this value $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{-t^2}{2n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \leq \frac{-t^2}{2} + c$$.

But without knowing exactly which $f(n) \in O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ we can't give a more precise value.